# IDE vs Library vs SDK vs Framework vs Toolkit

Tags: sdk, frameworks, ide, toolkit

Made a research before asking this but I couldn't really understand much of differences between what I'm asking above. In-depth information would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

API - a set of functions and structures (classes?) for performing a selected task (e.g. libcurl API for network requests)

A Framework is something you can build upon. Usually it is complete (or almost complete) to a point it can be started out of the box (but probably would`nt do anything useful) and provides APIs to override some functionality 
a toolkit is a set of utilities/tools you can use for some task (e.g. Kali Linux is a network penetration toolkit)

SDK (Software Developer`s Kit) is a toolkit (usually official) that can be used to interact with/program some device/entity. It also may provide APIs and frameworks internally. (e.g. Android SDK allows to develop, build, test and deploy applications for, well, Android. it describes APIs accessible from different OS versions. )

A toolkit is a set of utilities/tools you can use for some task (e.g. Kali Linux is a network penetration toolkit)